# Class 'Pusher\Pusher' not found - Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8, composer-php

I added

```
'Pusher' => Pusher\Pusher::class,
```

in my aliases[]

[image]

I still getting

[image]

I've tried

[image]

Comment: are you sure Pusher is included via composer?

Comment: How do I check ?

Comment: Look at composer.json, should be listed as a dependency, under the "require" key

Comment: yes, I have this line `"pusher/pusher-php-server": "~3.0"`

Comment: Did you run composer install after adding it?

Comment: Try doing `composer require pusher/pusher-php-server`.

Comment: yes I did. I have it in my composer.json

Comment: What do you get using `dd(Pusher\Pusher::class);` in tinker?

Comment: @kyo Having it in your `composer.json` is NOT the same as installing it, if you just added the text in the `.json` file.

Comment: I can't even get into the tinker commandline. Any php artisan command causing this error `Class 'Pusher\Pusher' not found`

Comment: Comment out the Pusher line in `config/app.php`.

Answer (score 3):

try this command and install it.

```
composer require pusher/pusher-php-server
```

Comment: It should be `composer require pusher/pusher-php-server`. Couldn't edit your answer for some reason

Answer (score 2):

you dont have to add `Pusher\Pusher` to `aliases`. Laravel should auto-discover `pusher-php-server`. Read the Driver Prerequisites @ [Laravel Broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting)

Answer (score 1):

To create an alias, the facade needs to know how that can be resolved via a service provider which doesn't come with just any php library. To use pusher in laravel with a facade which can be aliased, use https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-laravel/ instead. You could write your own service provider and facade on your own for pusher... but this library already does exactly that.

Answer (score -1):

are you sure that you've added

```
    use Pusher\Pusher;
```

at first of your script?

and I think that the class must be added to providers array